# Displaying Hidden Information using external JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, visibility

What I am doing is validating user input. At this time, I'm just validating for just the name to make sure the name is at least 6 characters long. I will add more validation, but I can't even get the error to display for just this. It does work if the script is on the HTML page but I want it externally because I have a lot I need to add.

When I have the js between  tags on the HTML page, it works: it displays the hidden by CSS "txtNameError" if less than 6 characters are entered.

When I have the js on an extrernal .js file, it doesn't work: it doesn't change it to visible if there are less than 6 characters.

Yet, the code is identical?

Here is the basic HTML for the "name portion":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="week12.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" placeholder="Name" /></td>
        <td><p class="error" id="txtNameError">Name must be at least 6 characters long.</p></td>
        <!--The p class "error" is set to hidden visibility using the CSS page. If they don't meet the requirements, then "txtNameError" becomes visible.-->
    </tr>
    <!--OTHER USER INPUT, THAT I'M NOT YET INCLUDING (just working on the name part now)-->
    <tr>
        <td><button onclick="validateForm();">Register</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I have the  tags below this with my function, it works: it makes txtNameError visible. But when I put my function on validate.js, it doesn't work at all.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
        var nameLength = name.length;
        if (nameLength < 6) {
            document.getElementById("txtNameError").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I have it in the HTML page, I include the  tags, when it's in it's own validate.js, I don't include the script tags.

Comment: When you debug this, is the function invoked at all?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Stepping through the code in the debugger, where specifically does it fail?  Are the elements found?  Are their properties being set?

Comment: Is `fucntion validateForm()` just a typo here, or do your code actually say that?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++. But I've tried to check the code at javascriptlint.com and no errors come up.

Comment: @OskarHane That's a typo! Sorry. it is "function". When I have the code between script tags on the HTML page it works. When I copy function validateForm() over to external .js file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled function incorrectly in your script.

Also in your html remove the ; in the onclick attribute. seems to have cleaned up the errors for me.

```
 function validateForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
        var nameLength = name.length;
        if (nameLength < 6) {
            document.getElementById("txtNameError").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
```

and

`<td><button onclick="validateForm();">Register</button></td>`

should be `<td><button onclick="validateForm()">Register</button></td>`

Additionally I re-wrote the setup using jQuery for easier checks on the html elements however if you require them to be in javascript I can look into re writing it again, check out my updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dhershman/365r5tg5/1/

Comment: I've changed that with the function, That was a typo from me typing half the code over because I'm just putting up the code I'm having issues with. It's not really like that on my files.    I took out the semi colon and am still getting no luck.

Comment: What is it this script is supposed to do, from what you've shown here the function executed is not scripted to do anything else.

Comment: The script makes txtNameError visible if the input is less than 6 characters. txtNameError is hidden using CSS. When the script is on the HTML page, it displays the error if less than 6 characters are entered. When it's on an external file, it does nothing if less than 6 characters are displayed.

Comment: So what I did was remove your current function and basically built it using jQuery you can find my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/365r5tg5/

 If you want to stick to Raw Javascript we can also look into those options.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out!

One of the other variables I'm pulling from the HTML page is trying to pull from the page before it's fully loaded. I removed it and it works, using an external .js file.

I will work on relocating/redoing that variable so hopefully I won't have that issue!

Thanks so much for the help, everyone! :)